# SQL Server Report with page columns only works in export to PDF

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder

I created a report (using Report Builder 3.0) which has two page "newsletter style" columns (I'm not talking about Tablix columns here). I put a tablix in column (because you can't really put something in the other columns). My data should continue in the second column before moving to the next page.

That only works when I export to PDF or TIF or use the print function from the report viewer. The report viewer itself completely ignores this setting (and has twice as many pages). Also export to other formats doesn't have this.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be built-in behavior. TIFF export is actually the same as printing with the ActiveX plug-in so those 2 are always related. No way to get it to work for the viewer or other formats...

Don't know what the behavior is in the Windows Forms report viewer control...

Answer (score 0):

When you fetch the content can you split that into 2 part and then say within report you have 2 controls that display each part of the content

## Here is the steps

1. Say you DB had 1 cell data
2. Split that into 2 parts within the DB itself (you will need to define the logic on where the split should happen)
3. When the data comes to report it comes as 2 rows 1 column even though in DB the data is 1 row 1 column
4. In Report you have 2 text/label controls and each display each rows

Hope that helps

Comment: First: this is a workaround which involves quite some work. Not a fix for my problem. Secondly: you can never get a good algorithm for where to split the data given the fact that your export or print method split differently already...